# When calling ReadDirectoryChangesW, only the first call returns any changes (both sync and async)

Tags: c++, winapi, readdirectorychangesw

The following is a minimal program which uses `ReadDirectoryChangesW`. The problem I am having is that only the first call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` returns. The second time through the loop it blocks forever no matter how many changes are made to the directory.

I have also attempted using the synchronous version and have the exact same problem.

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
  // Open the directory to monitor.
  HANDLE dir = ::CreateFileA(
      "G:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\eve online"
    , FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY
    , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE
    , NULL
    , OPEN_EXISTING
    , FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED
    , NULL
    );

  if (dir == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    std::cout << "Failed to open directory for change notifications!\n";
    return 1;
  }

  // Setup IOCP.
  HANDLE iocp = ::CreateIoCompletionPort(
      dir
    , NULL
    , NULL
    , 1
    );

  // Monitor.
  while (true) {
    std::array<char, 1024 * 8> buf;
    DWORD bytes_read;
    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    std::memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(overlapped));
    BOOL result = ::ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        dir
      , &buf.front()
      , buf.size()
      , false
      , FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME // Includes file creation.
      , &bytes_read
      , &overlapped
      , NULL
      );

    if (result == FALSE) {
      DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
      std::cout << "Call to ReadDirectoryChangesW failed! " << error << "\n";
      return 1;
    }

    // Wait for completion.
    ULONG_PTR key;
    LPOVERLAPPED overlapped_result;

    result = ::GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
        iocp
      , &bytes_read
      , &key
      , &overlapped_result
      , INFINITE
      );

    if (result == FALSE) {
      std::cout << "Call to GetQueuedCompletionStatus failed!\n";
      return 1;
    }

    // Print results!
    for (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *fni =
           reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *>(&buf.front());
         ;
         fni = reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *>(
           reinterpret_cast<char *>(fni) + fni->NextEntryOffset)) {
      std::wstring filename(fni->FileName, fni->FileName + fni->FileNameLength);
      std::wcout << "Got change: " << filename.c_str() << "\n";

      if (fni->NextEntryOffset == 0) break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few problems.

First, you're trying to output multi-byte string literals to `wcout`. You should turn them into wide strings by prepending L.

Second, the `FileNameLength` variable represents the length of the name in bytes, not characters. You should divide it by 2 to get the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

How are you compiling this?  Using Visual Studio it fails to compile because the third parameter to GetQueuedCompletionStatus is typed incorrectly.  The parameter should be a pointer to a pointer to ULONG, not a pointer to ULONG.  When I changed the declaration of the "key" variable to

ULONG_PTR key;

the programs works correctly.

Comment: I'm using VS2010. That change did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your print logic is causing a buffer overrun because fni->FileNameLength is in bytes, not characters.  Random memory corruption would explain why I got different results than you.

The fix is simply this:

std::wstring filename(fni->FileName, fni->FileName + fni->FileNameLength / sizoeof(fni->FileName[0]));